# ui-router preventDefault() but persist URL, or change URL of declared state

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

Two similar/related questions:

1) While in a `$stateChangeStart` event, is it possible to allow the url to change, but prevent the actual state transition?

If I use `event.preventDefault()`, it prevents the URL from updating.

2) Is it possible to change the url of a state that you've already created?

I've created a state with no url that I'm using to display different templates for unauthorized states (if a user doesn't have the proper authorization, they're redirected to this state, but I want the URL to reflect that they were trying to reach the original URL).

```
$stateProvider.state('unauthorized-role', {
    data: {
        targetState: null
    },
    views: {
        'main-view': {
            controller: 'UnauthorizedCtrl',
            templateUrl: '/src/app/role-unauthorized.tpl.html'
        }
    }
});
```

When I go to redirect to this state (in `$stateChangeStart`), I do the following:

```
ev.preventDefault();

var unauthState = $state.get('unauthorized-role');
unauthState.url = toState.url;
unauthState.data.targetState = toState;
$state.go(unauthState);
```

But it doesn't inherit the new url. Is it possible to change it somehow?

Answer (score 0):

```
$state.go(unauthState, { location: false });
```

Comment: The unauthState doesn't have a url when first defined, so I'm not trying to prevent it from updating the url, I'm trying to force it to update the URL when I added the state.url property after I defined the state.

Comment: right-- this should make it so that it doesn't change the url.  In other words, you go to /foo, your $stateChangeStart event triggers that the user is unauthorized to go to foo, so it transitions to the unauth state, without modifying the url, so the user should see /foo in the location bar and the content should be your unauthState ui-view.  Am I misunderstanding what you're trying to do?  Your original post says "but I want the URL to reflect that they were trying to reach the original URL", hence /foo in my example.